# Slider with Map Fragment v2 giving black screen

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using slider menu with google map V2. When I press slider menu button it gives me black screen for a while.

This happens only in android device versions 2.2 to 4.0 on later versions it seems to work fine.

Comment: Is hardware acceleration enabled in your manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seem like a known issue.

Have a look at these gmaps-api-issues reports. Maybe you can find a workaround for your case in comments.

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4659

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4639